# cannot set width of single character textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview

I have a custom textview element holding one element like so:

```
<com.blah.PinView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="25dp"
android:layout_height="15dp"
android:text="•"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="30sp" />
```

and i dynamically add these to a `LinearLayout` and the entry and movement is animated by a `LayoutAnimator`. The width of the `TextView` is wholly determined by the character(smaller for bullet and larger for other characters) it holds like so:

`[•][•][•][ 5 ]`

but i want the width to be the same for any character like so:

`[ • ][ • ][ • ][ 5 ]`

what's the problem here?

Comment: Insert some start/left and end/left padding. It'll work fine.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/iQABce8R

Comment: Adding padding didnt work. what did work for me was force setting layout params programatically.

Comment: i checked out the pastebin thing, and I'm afraid Im not familiar with spans. Will check that out tho. severly limited cause i dont know it

Comment: just call `setTransformationMethod` on your `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScaleXSpan to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
<com.blah.PinView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="•"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
     android:textSize="30sp" />
```

and for referrence follow this link;

https://github.com/DavidPizarro/PinView

Answer (score 0):

Padding will work as this is why padding is used.
Put these two lines.

```
android:paddingStart="3dp"
android:paddingEnd="3dp"
```

Or

```
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:paddingLeft="3dp"
```

You can adjust the padding size according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is used to define the size of widget from within the widget. So add padding to each or in the container for all. Try following:

```
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
```

Comment: dunno why someone downvoted... this actually seems to work

Comment: it feels like adding padding shouldn't work. but it does apparently. lemme check the layout bounds